# Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed

Tags: docker

I am having an issue with `docker compose up`. The following `docker-compose.yml` file works fine when I run `docker run tharsishq/evmos:dea1278`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  node0:
    container_name: evmosnode0
    image: "tharsishq/evmos:dea1278"
    ports:
      - "26656-26657:26656-26657"
    volumes:
      - ./build/node0/evmosd:/evmos:Z
    command:
      - /evmosd start --home /evmos
    networks:
      localnet:
        ipv4_address: 192.167.10.2

networks:
  localnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - 
          subnet: 192.167.10.0/16
```

However, when I try to run the same setup with `docker compose up`, I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/evmosd start --home /evmos": stat /evmosd start --home /evmos: no such file or directory: unknown
```

What could be causing this discrepancy?

I tried the following

Trial 1

```
version: '3'

services:
  node0:
    container_name: evmosnode0
    image: "tharsishq/evmos:dea1278"
    ports:
      - "26656-26657:26656-26657"
    volumes:
      - ./build/node0/evmosd:/evmos:Z
    command:
      - /evmosd
      - start
      - --home
      - /evmos
    networks:
      localnet:
        ipv4_address: 192.167.10.2

networks:
  localnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - 
          subnet: 192.167.10.0/16
```

I get the following error

```
Attaching to evmosnode0
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/evmosd": stat /evmosd: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Trial 2

```
version: '3'

services:
  node0:
    container_name: evmosnode0
    image: "tharsishq/evmos:dea1278"
    ports:
      - "26656-26657:26656-26657"
    volumes:
      - ./build/node0/evmosd:/evmos:Z
    command: /evmosd start --home /evmos
    networks:
      localnet:
        ipv4_address: 192.167.10.2

networks:
  localnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - 
          subnet: 192.167.10.0/16
```

I get

```
Attaching to evmosnode0
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/evmosd": stat /evmosd: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you specified the command, so here:

```
    command:
      - /evmosd start --home /evmos
```

Because of the `-`, that is a list, equivalent to `["/evmosd start --home /evmos"]`. When you have a list as you entrypoint, the first element will be the executable to run - including spaces and all options. That's the [exec form of ENTRYPOINT/CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint):

> Command line arguments to docker run will be appended after all elements in an exec form ENTRYPOINT, and will override all elements specified using CMD. This allows arguments to be passed to the entry point, i.e., docker run -d will pass the -d argument to the entry point. You can override the ENTRYPOINT instruction using the docker run --entrypoint flag.
>
> The shell form prevents any CMD or run command line arguments from being used, but has the disadvantage that your ENTRYPOINT will be started as a subcommand of /bin/sh -c, which does not pass signals. This means that the executable will not be the container’s PID 1 - and will not receive Unix signals - so your executable will not receive a SIGTERM from docker stop .

What you want instead, is to either use the [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example):

```yaml
    command: /evmosd start --home /evmos
```

or separate the exec form correctly:

```yaml
    command: ["/evmosd", "start", "--home", "/evmos"]
# alternatively:
    command:
      - /evmosd
      - start
      - --home
      - /evmos
```

Comment: I tried all the forms you mentioned just now and suprisingly none of them worked. And I get the same error for every form I just tried

Comment: The final part of the error must have changed somehow; the two forms I listed do different things so the error wouldn't be the same. Does `/evmosd` really exist inside the image?

Comment: yes `/evmosd` exists in the image and I am able to run it as well if I just do `docker run tharsishq/evmos:dea1278` only with docker compose it doesnt work

Comment: I just downloaded that image with another tag, and `/evmosd` doesn't exist; it's in `/usr/bin/evmosd`. You need to change `/evmosd` to either `evmosd` (without the misleading `/`) or to `/usr/bin/evmosd`.

Comment: Thanks!! If I put this `/usr/bin/evmosd` it works but I am really surprised how it was working prior to my docker upgrade

Comment: Maybe the path in some version of the image changed. By the way, if it helped solve the problem, please accept the answer.